# Pattern matching Makefile with multiple executable targets

Tags: build, makefile

I have a makefile that builds multiple executable targets prog0...prog99. All the compiler and link options are the same for each executable:

```
prog0: prog0.cpp prog0.h
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) prog0 prog0.cpp $(LINKFLAGS)

prog1: prog1.cpp prog1.h
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) prog1 prog1.cpp $(LINKFLAGS)
.
.
.
.
prog99: prog99.cpp prog99.h
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) prog99 prog99.cpp $(LINKFLAGS)
```

I was wondering if there is a pattern matching technique similar to building object files that could be applied to the above, so as to reduce the repetition of the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly:

```
prog%: prog%.cpp prog%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $< $(LINKFLAGS)
```