# How to build multiple targets with similar name?

Tags: c, unix, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

So I have the exact same question as the one below, but no one has answered it.

[Pattern matching Makefile with multiple executable targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479180/pattern-matching-makefile-with-multiple-executable-targets)

I am trying to build a series of small test files each have a pattern of "test*.c" to test my library.

I wanted to write a makefile that builds executables for every one of the test files all at once (each name: test1, test2, test3..etc.). However, I am not sure how to achieve that.
What I have so far is the following:

```
SRC := $(shell find *.c)
ALL_PROG := $(patsubst %.c, %, *.c)
.PHONY: all

all: $(ALL_PROG)

$(ALL_PROG): $(SRC)
    -gcc $< -o $@
```

This is a bad attempt because the targets take all .c files as dependency, which caused circular dependency.

Using shell script can get the job done very easily, but I am wondering if there's a way to do the same job.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(ALL_PROG): %: %.c` instead of `$(ALL_PROG): $(SRC)`.

---

Here is an example Makefile I might use with GNU `make`:

```
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -O2
LDFLAGS := -lm
PROGS   := $(patsubst %.c, %, $(wildcard *.c))

.PHONY: all clean test $(patsubst %, test@%, $(PROGS))

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS)

$(PROGS): %: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(patsubst %, test@%, $(PROGS)): test@%: %
    ./$^

test: $(patsubst %, test@%, $(PROGS))
```

As usual, note that the indentation should use a <kbd>Tab</kbd> rather than spaces; the editor used here on stackoverflow.com auto-converts them to spaces.

The `PROGS` variable will contain the names of all `*.c` files in the directory.

The `.PHONY:` directive tells Make which targets do not refer to actual files. The `$(patsubst %, test@%, $(PROGS))` expands to the list of executable names, with each name prepended with `test@`: if the directory contains files `foo.c` and `bar.c`, this expands to `test@foo test@bar`.

The `$(PROGS): %: %.c` recipe compiles each .c file to the corresponding binary.

The `$(patsubst %, test@%, $(PROGS)): test@%: %` recipe creates a test target for each binary. If we have files `foo.c` and `bar.c`, then this rule expands to `test@foo test@bar: test@%: %`. This means that for both `test@foo` and `test@bar` targets, the corresponding `test@%` target requires the `%` binary. The `./$^` in turn expands to `./%`, and thus the binary name. (If you don't want Make to show the command being run, use `@./$^`. If you don't care if a test fails, use `-./$^`.)

The `test` recipe expands to `test@foo` `test@bar` if we have `foo.c` and `bar.c`; i.e. all possible test targets.

You can run `make clean test` to recompile all .c files in the directory, and execute them.

If you are only worried about a specific test program, say `foo.c`, you can run `make test@foo`, which will recompile the program if `foo.c` is newer than `foo`.

Comment: Just want to clarify, the "$(patsubst %, test@%, $(PROGS)): test@%: %" means for every target produced by the pattern, each target (test@%) requires (%). So the second colon indicates a dependency, but what does the first colon formally meant (named?) Is there a source that you can direct me to? This is the first time of me seeing two colons. Thank you very much.

Comment: @J.S.M: It is `targets: target-pattern: prerequisite-pattern`, as described in the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage). Whenever I write Makefiles, I do keep a browser window open to the [single-page version of GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. I am updating a simple make file which builds multiple targets. You can modify it as your requirement.

```
TEST1       = test1.exe
TEST2       = test2.exe

### Executable Program Files ###

all : $(TEST1) $(TEST2)

$(TEST1) : test1.c
    gcc -o $(TEST1) test1.c 

$(TEST2) : test2.c
    gcc -o $(TEST2) test2.c
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be suitable for small number of tests; however, what I would like to do is to build a series of tests, say 20 and more. That's why, I want to know if there's a pattern rule that I can write to build more tests without having to write individual rules.