# Makefile to execute multiple programs (c/c++)

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am a novice user of makefile, I have created rules(run1, run2 etc) to execute c and c++ objects separately(separate compilation is successful c/c++, also need to execute them separately) but it seems not working as expected, could anyone tell were it went wrong and how to correct it

```
TARGET_EXEC ?=

BUILD_DIR ?= .
SRC_DIRS ?= .

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.cpp -or -name *.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

CC = gcc
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
CPPFLAGS = -g -lws2_32 -Wno-write-strings

.PHONY: all run1 run2 run3 clean
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
    @echo "Build completed"

# c source
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling C sources"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(basename $(<F))
    @echo "Compiled successfully"

# c++ source
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @echo "Compiling C++ sources"
    @$(CXX) -o $(basename $(<F)) $(CXXFLAGS) $< $(CPPFLAGS)
    @echo "Compiled successfully"

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning"
    @$(RM) -r *.exe
    @echo "Cleaned up"

run1: $(OBJS)
$(OBJS)=$(SRCS)
$(SRC_DIRS)/%.c.o: %.c
    @echo "from run1"
    ./$(basename $(<F)) ${ARGS}

run2: $(OBJS)
$(OBJS)=$(SRCS)
$(SRC_DIRS)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @echo "from run2"
    ./$(basename $(<F)) ${ARGS}
```

command used: `make run1`

output:

```
    from run1
     -> execution
    from run2
     -> execution
```

Expected output

```
    from run1
--> execution of exe created
```

Moreover I am trying to pass arguments which I have referred from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2214593/1970427) to pass on to make run. eg:

```
make ARG="-p TCP -n 127.0.0.1 -e 10006 -l 1" run2
```

also let me know if this can be done without any issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build multiple targets with similar name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662359/how-to-build-multiple-targets-with-similar-name)

Comment: I'm not seeing how that's a duplicate.  It doesn't address OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

look at the rules:

```
run1: $(OBJS)
$(OBJS)=$(SRCS)
$(SRC_DIRS)/%.c.o: %.c
    @echo "from run1"
    ./$(basename $(<F)) ${ARGS}
```

The first line says `run1` is dependent on `$(OBJS)`, but does not have any explicit recipes.  The next line does an assignment, and the last line defines a pattern rule for all `.c.o` files with some recipes.  These recipes are *not* associated with `run1`.   When you run `make run1`, it will build the dependencies (`$(OBJS)`), which includes all `cpp.o` and `c.o` files.  Therefore it will run both pattern rules, and output both your lines.

What I think you want to do, is to split `$(OBJS)` into `$(C_OBJS)`, and `$(CPP_OBJS)`, and then have  `run1` dependent on one set, and `run2` dependent on the other, and then have `$(TARGET_EXEC)` depend on both.